# Calculate the total possible number of combinations out of x permutations, that's would sum to the same value.

Tags: combinatorics

Is it possible to calculate the total number of combinations that sum to a given value from x permutations?

For example, a 4 digit combination has 10,000 permutations from 0000 to 9999. How could one calculate the total number of combinations that would sum/score to, say 10 for example, (e.g. 1+9+0+0 = 10, 7+3+0+0 = 10 and so on...)

Hope that question makes sense,

Thank you!

Comment: What you wish to find is the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 10$ in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions that $x_i \leq 9$ for $1 \leq i \leq 4$.  This is a [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem.

Comment: Multinomial theorem?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig But the order doesn't seem to matter here.

Comment: @SameerBaheti  A combination lock is unlocked by producing the correct *sequence* of four numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Simple
a+b+c+d=0(mod 10)
so for each a, b, c fixed there is a d element such that a+b+c+d=0(mod 10)
since a,b and c can take 10 different values each you have 10^3=1000 possible combionations.